# First android project creation on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Right now I'm trying to learn android programming but there's something wrong with the first step every time I'm creating a new android project in eclipse it's gives me a red x sing on some folders and i can't run anything cause it also gives me error msg ( please fix the errors  then run)

[image]

Comment: That means there's an error in those lines. Update your question and add those files, and someone might be able to help. Also, you should switch to Android Studio instead of Eclipse - I don't think Eclipse is officially supported any more.

Comment: Did my answer work? Feel free to ask me any questions if it didn't. If it did, make sure to mark it best answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

This means there is some error within the code which is in that specific folder or package. Once you clear those errors, it should go away. Is your "myfirstapp" program running when you hit run, or is there an error in the console below? That error corresponds to the red "x" that you are seeing. Once you troubleshoot your errors, the x's on the folders and packages will disappear. If you wan't, you can post the code you are having issues with, or look up the specific error that it is displaying for you and try to resolve it. Best of luck!

If you found this answer useful please like and mark as best answer. It would help a lot!

Comment: yes bro every time i hit run it gives me a error msg like that ( please fix the errors an then run ) i didn't even right anything i just created new project every time it's gives me the same :(

Comment: Did you put in a public static void main (String [] args) { } That is the body of a java program.

Comment: you know when you go to (in eclipse) to new then new android project then you hit finish to creat the project ? that's all i done nothing more

Comment: Then don't worry about the x's for now; once you put actual code in, and learn java syntax, you'll learn how to get rid of the x's. Since there isn't any code, there's obviously going to be an error because... well... There's no code! In general what i;m saying is that you shouldn't worry until you actually get coding.

Comment: i know how to write java code i'm not professional but i gained knowledge to make me learn android programming , but you know when you create a project there's codes lines  by default

Comment: Do you have a main part in your program? Often times the default code doesn't have the main part unless you put a different setting.  Otherwise, you have to manually enter it. Try putting in some code into your class, and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

1) Because, In xml file first you have to solve the error.
2) After that clean the project error will automatically get resolved.